# iPhone app needing print to pdf to email or something similar?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, xcode, email

I am developing an iPhone app for my company that was originally a mobile website.  The whole site works perfectly and is formatted correctly on the various iPhones. The last little bit I need to create is a button that would email and send out the data.  Basically the app is a sales ticket replacement.  It has all out products on it and you would add to cart, the cart would transfer over to a checkout page, and it's supposed to convert to a PDF or something and email that data to someone.  On the checkout page I have input fields for the sales agent to type in information such as customer info and dates.  I cannot figure out how I could make this work using xcode or even html/css/javascript.  I really don't want to use a php form as the app is supposed to be self-staining without internet (the email would sit in the outbox of the native email app until a connection is established).  Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?  I'm losing my mind!  Thank you!

Comment: Can you not get xcode to send a http request with the required information? to an external API? Or take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendingaMailMessage.html

Comment: have you looked into this http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: @KunalBalani So far this is looking promising.  I will let you know how it comes out.

Comment: So we weren't able to get it work in the way we wanted, however, we found a service called jotForm that seemed to work fine for emailing our invoices.  Thanks!